# ASP.NET CORE Adding and Removing Roles

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

As the Title says I am trying to Add the roles from the array I get if the Roles do not match the ones that user has. Those that do match I want to be removed. here is my controller logic.
string id is the name of the role I get.
Also when I run this code I get an exception saying 
"**User security stamp cannot be null.**"

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, User user, string[] roles)
{
    if (id != user.Id)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var listOfRoles = await privateUser.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach (var role in listOfRoles.Except(roles))
            {
                await privateUser.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role);
            }

            foreach(var role in roles.Except(listOfRoles))
            {
                await privateUser.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UserExists(user.Id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a user obtained via a POST, which is not only bad practice, but won't even work here, because you're not posting the full `User` object. Namely, the value of `SecurityStamp` is missing, which is what the exception is telling you.

Do not post the `User`. Instead, use the user id to fetch it from the database:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, string[] roles)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // the rest of your code
```

**UPDATE (for modifying user at the same time)**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, User model, string[] roles)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // map over the values from `model` (i.e. the posted `User`)
    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
    // etc.

    // use `user` not `model` for role management functions
```

Comment: This is a scaffolded for editing the user.
it's been there so thats why it was like that. I will use your advice.

Comment: If this is a view for editing a user, you may still need the `User` param (although you should really be using a view model instead). However, the user instance for your role adding stuff should be a user from the database, still, not what was posted.

Comment: Thanks it helped me !